# Python - Regular Expression keyword search with using a slash ("/") in the Regular Expression

Tags: python, python-re, slash

I can't figure this one out... Regular Expressions are not friendly to me!

```
phrase = "www.usatoday.com/story/travel/airline-news/2022/10/04/airplane-behaviors-reclining-seats-overhead-bins-shoes/8129315001/"

text = '/story/'       ## uses BOTH "/"

if re.findall('\\b'+text+'\\b', phrase):
    found = True
    print(found)  else:
    found = False
    print(found)
```

regular expressions with slash ("/") are not friendly.

how do I fix this to do an exact match find of "/story/" in the phrase and return a true or false response. I can do the search via regular expressions except I don't know how to do it with the "/".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `re.findall('/story/', "www.usatoday.com/story/travel/airline-news/2022/10/04/airplane-behaviors-reclining-seats-overhead-bins-shoes/8129315001/")`  I am not sure what you were trying to do using `'\\b'`...

Comment: `\b` will make it not match...just use `regex = r"/story/"`

Comment: you need to escape the `/` by  back slash "\". In your case, pattern should be `"\/story\/"`.

Answer (score -1):

I hope it will work for your solution,

```
import re
phrase = "www.usatoday.com/story/travel/airline-news/2022/10/04/airplane-behaviors-reclining-seats-overhead-bins-shoes/8129315001/"

text = '/story/'       ## uses BOTH "/"
text = text.replace('/', '')
re.findall(f'\/{text}\/', phrase)
```